# display: flex сжимает всю секцию

Tags: html, css, flexbox

У меня такой вопрос, не подскажете почему display: flex сжимает всю секцию?
А мне фактически нужно, чтобы мой блок с иконками был justify-content: space-between, но flex почему то это всё сжимает. 
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```css
.skills {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills__content {
  max-width: 956px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.skills__title {
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.skills__mixing {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.skills__programs-colums {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.skills .img {
  width: 89px;
  height: 88px;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills" class="page__skills skills">
         <div class="skills__content _container">
            <div class="skills__body">
               <div class="skills__description">
                  <div class="skills__title">
                     <p>Skills</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="skills__mixing">
                     <p>I work in such programs as:</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="skills__programs-colums">
                  <div class="skills__photoshop">
                     <div class="img">
                        <img src="img/Photoshop_icon.png" alt="">
                     </div>
                     <div class="title">
                        <p>Adobe <br>
                           Photoshop</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="stars">
                        <div class="first__star">
                           <img src="img/Star.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="second__star">
                           <img src="img/Star.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="third__star">
                           <img src="img/Star.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fourth__star">
                           <img src="img/Star.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fifth__star">
                           <img src="img/Star-1.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="skills__illustrator">
                     <div class="img">
                        <img src="img/Illustrator_icon.png" alt="">
                     </div>
                     <div class="title">
                        <p>Adobe <br>
                           Illustrator</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="stars"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="skills__after-effects">
                     <div class="img">
                        <img src="img/After_Effects_icon.png" alt="">
                     </div>
                     <div class="title">
                        <p>Adobe <br>
                           After Effects</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="stars"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="skills__figma">
                     <div class="img">
                        <img src="img/figma_icon.png" alt="">
                     </div>
                     <div class="title">
                        <p>Figma</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="stars"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на About me не смотрите, тут вопрос только к секции Skills

Comment: Вам нужно дать флекс для блока, в котором находятся "карточки" скилов. Так же нужно прикладывать не скриншот, а минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, я как раз это сразу и сделал, и всё равно ничего не работает

Comment: Добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример, иначе тут гадалок нет.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, я добавил код

Answer (score 0):

Код сильно перегружен и показан не весь. Активно используете width для div, что делать совершенно не нужно. Масса лишних обёрток.

В общем случае Вам достаточно div, в котором лежат четыре img. Хотя, по-хорошему, эти иконки следует положить в фон, потому что они не являются контентом.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="skills__programs-colums">
  <img src="#" alt="Фотошоп" />
  
  <img src="#" alt="Иллюстратор" />
  
  <img src="#" alt="Автоэффект" />
  
  <img src="#" alt="Фигма" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.skills__programs-colums { 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Ну да, в какой-то степени вы правы, но я делаю по BEM, и картинки я запихиваю вместе с текстом в один маленький блок, у меня ещё там должны звёздочки стоять, но не в этом сейчас дело. И вот я не понимаю почему у меня всё вот так сжимается, хотя есть блок повыше и он отлично работает, там почти такой же код.

Comment: В самой высокой степени) И, причём тут БЭМ?) Ну, да ладно. Ок, display: flex; ничего не сжимает - не умеет просто. В .skills__programs-colums всё ок, стили работают. Ограничена ширина в родителе. Судя по Вашему скрину, секция этим не грешит, следовательно, ограничение в .skills__body, который Вы не показываете)

Comment: Ну у меня как раз в skills__body ничего не прописано

Comment: Ну, я хоть и ясновидящий, но не настолько) Если взять тот код, который Вы здесь разместили, то ничего не сжимается: https://wampi.ru/image/RQB5LNP